# Chromeの拡張機能”Web Scraper”について

Tags: python, web-scraping, chrome-extension

Chromeの拡張機能”Web Scraper”について
Pythonでスクレイピングを学習する前に、プログラムなしで利用できる”Web Scraper”をいうChromeの拡張機能を利用してみました。

試しにヤフオクで「Mac Book Pro」で検索をかけ「おすすめ順」の
ページを表示させました。
サイト名を[Mac book Pro]とし、URLは上記のページのUrlを貼りcreateしました。

次に[id]をItemとし、Multipleにチェックを入れ「Type」をElementにしました。
そして「select」を押して実際は添付画像にある、青色の部分（要素全体）を取得したいのですが、実際に選択され赤く変色するのはイメージのみです。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

”Web Scraper”を使って、「画像」、「商品名」、「現在価格」、「即決価格」、「入札数」、「残り日数」といった要素すべてを取得する場合は「Type」をElementにするのではなく別のものにする必要があるのでしょうか？

やり方が間違っているのかもしれません。正しく取得できる方法を教えて下さい。

*これはあくまで扱い方の練習で実際にスクレイピングをするわけではありません。（ショッピングサイトの多くは禁止されてるようです。）

Comment: この辺の記事を参考にしてみては？ [chrome拡張機能...](https://pig-data.jp/blog_news/blog/scraping-crawling/web-scraper/), [スクレイピングのChrome拡張...](https://tokidoki-web.com/2020/10/%E3%82%B9%E3%82%AF%E3%83%AC%E3%82%A4%E3%83%94%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B0%E3%81%AEchrome%E6%8B%A1%E5%BC%B5%E3%80%8Cfreewebscraping%E3%80%8D%E3%82%92%E7%B4%B9%E4%BB%8B%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6%E3%82%84%E3%82%93/), [【備忘録】Chrome拡張機能...](https://qiita.com/ka-ko/items/2ef0c6870bb8a174f35f), [Scraperの使用方法...](https://agency-star.co.jp/column/scraper), [\[Chrome 拡張機能\]...](https://blog.withachristianwife.com/2020/05/11/list-note-entries-with-web-scraper/)